# Fixed fullscreen div over body with scroll bars

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a fixed fullscreen div `position:fixed; width:100%; height:100%;` cover the body of the page including the scroll bars?

I know I can just set the body to `overflow:hidden;` but the issue I'm having is that I want the fullscreen div to fade-in but changing the body's overflow changes the width of the fullscreen div as it fades in and out.

Here's a demo.  You can see changing the overflow of the body changes the width of the fixed div.
http://jsfiddle.net/bk63qejf/

Comment: You have to give overflow: hidden to hide the scrollbar. You can set the width of the fixed div more than 100% so that you don't see much difference during the fadein/out thing. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/bk63qejf/1/)

Comment: the same issue have in modals of bootstrap.

Comment: i dont think it is possible with css only use jquery if the div is visible change body style to overflow hidden else if hidden change to overflow scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the comments to my post.  I was able to figure out a solution.

The answer is you need to make the scrollable content positioned fixed also using `width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; overflow:auto;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/bk63qejf/2/

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly. You just have to add a position fixed to your body and html tags as well. See css code below:

```
html, body { margin:0; padding:0; width: 100%; height: 100%; position:fixed;}
#fullscreen{ position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: gray; color:white; word-break: break-all; overflow:auto;}
```

Hope it helps :-)